# Ext.Ajax.request does not work with no reason

Tags: android, ajax, extjs, request, sencha-touch-2

I have a huge problem and I do not find a solution on the internet. When I want to login in my app on my mobile device (Sencha Touch App on Android) nothing happens except failure.
I think there will not be send any request because there does not arrive any request in the back end.

I have set `<access origin="*" />` ...

Hope anyone has an idea.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: fullUrl,
    params: params,
    method: "GET",
    //enable basic authentication
    withCredentials: true,
    // need useDefaultXhrHeader: false and disableCaching: true to get cookies to work.
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    disableCaching: true,
    username: credentials.username,
    password: credentials.password,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (data) {
        callback(self._handleSuccessResult(data.responseText));
    },
    failure: function (data, request) {
        callback(self._handleErrorResult(data));
    }
});
```

**OUTPUT data and request:**

```
data : {
    "request" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "headers" : {
            "Authorization" : "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "options" : {
            "url" : "https:XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "params" : {
                "i_uname" : "KLAUS",
                "datatype" : "GET"
            },
            "method" : "GET",
            "withCredentials" : true,
            "useDefaultXhrHeader" : false,
            "disableCaching" : true,
            "username" : "XXXXXXXXX",
            "password" : "XXXXXXXXX",
            "timeout" : 10000
        },
        "async" : true
    },
    "requestId" : 1,
    "status" : 404,
    "statusText" : "Not Found",
    "responseText" : "",
    "responseXML" : null,
    "responseBytes" : null
}

request : {
    "url" : "https:XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "params" : {
        "i_uname" : "KLAUS",
        "datatype" : "GET"
    },
    "method" : "GET",
    "withCredentials" : true,
    "useDefaultXhrHeader" : false,
    "disableCaching" : true,
    "username" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "password" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "timeout" : 10000
}
```

**and the desktop browser code:**

```
params["jsonencode"] = "X";
// browser jsonp call
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: fullUrl,
    callbackKey: "myjson",
    params: params,
    success: function (data) {
        callback(self._handleSuccessResult(data));
    },
    failure: function (error) {
        callback(self._handleErrorResult(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: If you go on failure, can you console.log() data and request ?

Comment: is this working on Desktop Browser ?

Comment: @MohitSaxena : yes it is. but there is another code. (I will post it in my question)

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier : I also post it in the question, an there is 404. I dont know WHAT is not found

Comment: is that issue resolved? I am facing same issue from android device whicle making ajax call. however same call is working absolutley fine in ios. I am getting 404 error on ajax call where as same application on ios is able to make ajax call